# Есть ли простой способ обнаружить блокировку порта ISP?

Tags: сеть

Есть ли простой способ обнаружить блокировку портов ISP и хостинга которую провайдеры применили только для конкретного сайта по отношению к определенному пользователю (с реальным IP). Можно ли как то отследить по всему маршруту прохождения трафика, и выявить ip маршрутизатора и увидеть какие tcp порты на нем заблокированы не пускают на запрашиваемый сайт? Пробовал смотреть tcpdump  программой Wireshark,  но увидел только что уходят запросы Destination port: http (80)и запрос установить соединение по этому порту Connection establish request (SYN):

Comment: Если отдельные порты то ни как. Если любое взаимодействие не проходит то смотреть traceroute и ping с записью маршрута. И желательно конечно иметь доступ на обе стороны, что бы можно было увидеть и исходящий трафик от вызывающего и поступающий со стороны сервера

Comment: Но вообще ISP обычно таким не занимаются, что бы блокировать определенных пользователей отностительно конкретного сервиса. Им это не нужно. Блокировка чаще всего происходит со стороны самого сайта

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на свой вопрос. Есть такая команда tcptraceroute (tracetcp) — аналогичная traceroute программа, но предназначена для диагностики TCP соединений; вместо UDP-пакетов использует TCP-пакеты открытия соединения (SYN|ACK) с указанным сервисом, в результате получаем информацию о времени и маршруте прохождения пакетов по заданным портам. Скачать ее можно на GitHub.. Всем удачи!!